# Show f is surjective

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. Choose a fixed $g$ in $G$. Show the function $f : G → G$ given by $\phi(x)=gxg^{-1}$ is surjective

Well I'd say it makes good sense since f goes from G to G, but I'm sure how to show it algebraically (like for $f : A → B$ for all $b\in B$ there is some $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=b$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(x) = gxg^{-1}$, then $f(g^{-1}yg) = gg^{-1}ygg^{-1} = y$

Comment: Why is $g^{-1}yg$ in G? Because $\phi$ is injective?

Comment: @Jta - If $g, y \in G$ then $g^{-1}yg \in G$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Try to show that it has an inverse, which is of a similar form.